# Nodejs - writing and saving files

Tags: node.js, express

I am investigating how to download files to a user's local machine but I'm not quite sure what I need in order to do this. I'm using Nodejs and Express with Angularjs on the front-end.

User's can write text into a textarea and it's this text that will be written to the file.

To do this I have:

```
...
fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFile('filename.txt', textarea.text, function (err) {
  if (err) return console.log(err);
  res.send(200);
});
...
```

Once the file is created how do I get it to download on the user's machinea?

Comment: Do you even need to save the file to the server? You don't to just let the user download it.

Comment: Actually no - how would I go about this?

Comment: Then I wouldn't save it on the server - see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need to store the file on the server, you could just sent it back to the user directly:

```
res.attachment('filename.txt');
res.set('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
res.send(textarea.text);
```

This is not only simpler but also improves performance (no disk i/o) and more secure (no untrusted files on your server).

Comment: I agree - just looking at `res.attachment` in the Express docs.

Comment: Very good, amended the answer now that stackoverflow is back up.

Answer (score 2):

Use `res.download`

```
res.download('filename.txt');
```

http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#res.download